# I can/could travel in July

Tags: modal-verbs

1. *I **can** travel in July because my exams will **definitely** be finished at the beginning of that month.*
2. *I **could** travel in July because my exams will **probably** be finished at the beginning of that month.*

Do 1) and 2) both sound correct and natural, especially sentence 2), without any additional context?

Comment: Yes, both are correct. (1) implies 'it will be possible', (2) 'it would be possible if that were to be the date finally agreed upon'.

Comment: Do both suggest he *may* travel in July?

Comment: I suppose they do in the sense that neither says he will definitely go, only that it is possible.